# Solving $d = \frac12t - \frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(\pi t) $ for $t$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I'm a musician working on an audio project based on a movement model, and I'm struggling with an equation that's beyond my limited math. I have the following function for what is essentially displacement given time, given $t$ in the range $0$-$1$:

$$
d(t) = \frac12t - \frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(\pi t)
$$

...but I what I need instead is $t(d)$, time given displacement. How can I rewrite it?

Comment: As the answer below says, there is no analytic (formula) solution. You could plot a graph of $d$ against $t$ and read off the t required in 0 to 1 for a given d. Alternatively, you could use a numerical solver. Goal Seek in Excel is easy to use - put any t value in cell A1 and the d(t) formula in cell B1. Go to Data, What If Analysis, Goalseek and change the A1 value to preduce a required d value in A2.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for attracting attention to this Excel function (that I didn't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your equation under the form:

$$2 d(t)=t-\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(t),$$

you are in the framework of a classical issue: [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation):

$$M=\underbrace{E-e \sin E}_{k(E)},$$

historically connected with Kepler's work in astronomy (circa 1610): variables $M$ and $E$ are resp. the so-called mean anomaly and the eccentric anomaly of a planet, and $0 \le e < 1$ a fixed parameter (eccentricity of the elliptical trajectory of the planet). But we don't need to dive into astronomy...

There is no exact closed-form formula giving $E$ as a function of $M$, but there are different numerical solving methods for obtaining $E$ when $M$ is given. But one can give an approximate closed form formula based on a series expansion (to be found in the Wikipedia article mentionned above) in which we keep the first three terms,

$$E \approx\frac{1}{1-e}M-{\frac {e}{(1-e)^{4}}}{\frac {M^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac{(9e^{2}+e)}{(1-e)^{7}}}{\frac {M^{5}}{5!}}$$

which, numerically, gives, with $e=1/\pi$:

$$E\approx 1.4669*M-0.2457*M^3+0.1499*M^5$$

which means, returning to your own variables:

$$t \approx 1.4669*(2d)-0.2457*(2d)^3+0.1499*(2d)^5 \tag{1}$$

This approximation is excellent in the range you consider : $0 \le t \le 1$ (see figure below).

If you want to still improve this approximation, add the term $(-0.1194 * (2d)^7)$ to the right hand side of (1).

[image]

Fig. 1: *Graphical representation of the variations of Kepler function $k$ (in red) and its (approximate) inverse $k^{-1}$ (in blue). Please note that the curve of $k^{-1}$ has been reflected with respect to the first quadrant bissector testifying the quality of the approximation; indeed, the two curves cannot be distinguished (there is a perfect overlay of the blue and the red curves) but at their ends.*

Comment: Just added a graphical representation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find an inverse function. It is not analytically possible in closed form as it is a transcendental equation to be solved.

Differential solution is perhaps unavoidable.
The method outlined below involves setting up a second order ode for an inverse function and numerically integrating the same. Primes on $y$ are differentiations with respect to time $t$.

$$ y = \frac{t}{2}-\frac{\sin \pi t}{2 \pi}$$
$$ y' = \frac{1}{2}- \frac{\cos \pi t}{2}$$
$$ y''= \frac{\pi}{2}\sin \pi t $$

For interchanging of axes or to seek an inverse function the following differential transformations are necessary:

$$y'\to \frac{1}{y'};~~ y''\to \frac{-y''}{y^{'3}};$$

resulting in the required ode whose solution is cut pasted next.

$$ y'' = -\pi^2 {y^{'3}}(\frac{y}{2}-t)$$

It has the periodic interval $ (0,0)-(1,2) $. $y$ axis label symbol is retained as $y$.

Good luck for your musical composition!

[image]